# AspectJ annotated based pointcuts not being invoked

Tags: java, android, aspectj, aop

I am attempting to create an android library that checks if internet is available before executing a method that has a custom annotation I have defined. I'm using AspectJ to accomplish this.

My annotation is as follows :

```
@Target({METHOD}) @Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface InternetRequired  {

}
```

Now for my aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class CilantroAspect
{

    private static final String POINTCUT_METHOD = "execution(@com.cilantro.service.InternetRequired * *(..))";
    private static final String POINTCUT_METHOD2 ="@annotation(com.cilantro.service.InternetRequired)";
    ;

    @Pointcut(POINTCUT_METHOD2)
    public void internetAnnotatedMethod() {
    }

    @Around("internetAnnotatedMethod()")
    public void checkInternetConnectivity(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Log.v("Aspect","advice being triggered");
        if (Cilantro.isConnected()) {
            joinPoint.proceed();
        } else {
            Cilantro.Toast("Internet not available");
        }
    }
}
```

Snippet of my activity with the annotated method.

```
    ....
    Cilantro.init(this);
    test();
}

@InternetRequired
public void test()
{
    Toast.makeText(this,"Test method",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

When I run my android app the around advice is not being triggered. I tried using POINTCUT_METHOD and POINTCUT_METHOD2. Still no luck.

My android app is configured to use Aspect J so I know that's not the problem because if I make errors within the pointcut definitions it's detected..but just to be sure let me share.

Main build script

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.uphyca.gradle:gradle-android-aspectj-plugin:0.9.+'
}
....
```

module containing Aspects

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'android-aspectj' 
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The around advice wasn't being triggered because I was using annotations related to the Aspect from the app level while the aspect was contained in the library. For the aspects to be weaved into the app module at compile time I had to simply publish the library to maven (local for testing and maven central for distribution) and then include the library as a project dependency in a gradle plugin which contains the AspectJ weaving tasks.The plugin is then applied to the app's module.

Here's a snippet of my plugin that's written in groovy. I add my library that contains my Aspects and then run the weaving tasks on the app's module.

```
project.dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:flender-runtime:1.0'
    // TODO this should come transitively
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.5'
}

variants.all { variant ->

    variant.dex.doFirst {
        String[] args = [
                "-showWeaveInfo",
                "-1.5",
                "-inpath", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                "-aspectpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                "-d", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                "-classpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                "-bootclasspath", project.android.bootClasspath.join(File.pathSeparator)
        ]
        log.debug "ajc args: " + Arrays.toString(args)

        MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(true);
        new Main().run(args, handler);
```

For a complete example of how this is done you can check my library out on github https://github.com/jd-alexander/flender